# Android : Gostaria de chamar uma imagem do perfil do facebook para perfil do usuario do app

Tags: android, facebook

Estou com dúvidas a respeito de que código usar para chamar essa imagem do perfil do face, para o perfil do meu usuário, alguém pode me ajudar a respeito?

Answer (score 1):

Vai depender muito da tecnologia usada para desenvolvimento, mais basicamente você vai ter que usar a API do Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

No caso do Android você tem que implementar algo como:

```
/* faz a chamada REST */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/picture",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* Trata o resultado lendo o objeto GraphResponse */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Entendi, é para Android que estou desenvolvendo, e e estou usando a ferramenta Android Studio, sou iniciante nessa parte de desenvolvimento, essa chamada eu faço no meu onCreate?
Porque eu quero chamar essa imagem em qualquer parte do meu app atraves da ID dela, eu teria que usar em todos os meus painéis . java?
ou com o "public void" eu consigo fazer essa chamada em qualquer parte do meu app?

Comment: você pode criar uma classe public com um método que execute esse trecho de código e utilizar essa classe sempre que precisar. Procure exemplos mais completos na internet com um projetinho de exemplo. Acho que irá lhe ajudar mais.

Comment: Em uma rápida pesquisa achei isso: http://www.cbsoft.dimap.ufrn.br/pdfs/Minicurso_2.pdf é baseado em eclipse, mais o código fonte é um só

Comment: Nossa que ótimo, estou lendo o pdf, muito obrigado, creio que com isso eu consigo já avançar meu projeto, muito obrigado Julio, abraços!

Comment: @DesenvolvimentoODmidia, por nada, caso tenha atendido, aceite a resposta por favor